# How to compute stock returns in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I know this is a very basic question but i have just started learning vba and am having difficulty understanding how to compute daily returns from price array.here is the program i have written,i am unable to understand the error.would really appreciate it if someone could help me out here.the program compiles without error but the function returns a value error.

```
Function ch2array(vdata As Variant)
    If TypeOf vdata Is Range Then
        ch2array = vdata.Value
    Else
        ch2array = vdata
    End If
End Function
```

```
Function dailyret(rng)
    rng = ch2array(rng)
    Dim i, j    As Integer
    Dim nr, nc  As Integer

    nc = UBound(rng, 2)
    nr = UBound(rng, 1)

    Dim gm()    As Double
    ReDim gm(1 To nr, 1 To nc)

    For j = 1 To nc
        For i = 1 To nr
            gm(i, j) = (Application.Index(rng, j, i) / Application.Index(rng, j, i - 1)) - 1
        Next i
    Next j

    dailyret = gm
End Function
```

Comment: What error do you get, and at which line?

Comment: Please also include the code for `ch2array`.

Comment: Hi Bruce,There seems to be no error in the program,cause it works just fine.but i do not get the required answer for the function,i get the #VALUE error

Comment: Hi Ralph, i have added the code for ch2array

Comment: Do a `for each e of rng | debug.print e` and see if that gives you the expected results.

Comment: Hi Findwindow,I have included the function..but it doesnt change the result.

Comment: Uh we're debugging here, not looking to change results yet.

Comment: Is `Function dailyret(rng)` supposed to return a value, an array or a range? I think you need to turn `Explicit On` and qualify every variable and function with the appropriate type.

Comment: Do you want to press a button to compute _all_ stock return values, or have a user function that returns one stock return value? To make a function return an array is doable, but more complex, and it only works for  fixed number of data points. I suggest to do the first, and have a calculate button which calls a `Sub` that manipulates the values.

Comment: thanks a lot ja72! i wanted to write a function to return an array of returns for an price array of 20 stocks..but your code helped get a good idea of what i should be doing...thanks again for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do get something like this:

[image: pic]

Run this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FillROR()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("B2")
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    If IsEmpty(rng.Value2) Then
        'Missing data
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If IsEmpty(rng.Offset(1, 0).Value2) Then
        'Only one price point
        Exit Sub
    End If
    n = rng.End(xlDown).Row - rng.Row + 1
    Set rng = rng.Resize(n, 1)

    Dim prices As Variant
    prices = rng.Value2

    Dim ror As Variant
    'Ror can only be caclulated for n-1 values
    ReDim ror(1 To n - 1, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To n - 1
        ror(i, 1) = prices(i + 1, 1) / prices(i, 1) - 1#
    Next i

    'Move one column to the right, one row down
    rng.Offset(1, 1).Resize(n - 1, 1).Value2 = ror
End Sub
```